# Paste multiple formatted cell value to a few other worksheets at once

Tags: excel, vba

I have the cell, which has been formatted in various ways:

https://www.thewindowsclub.com/add-multiple-formatting-to-your-text-in-a-single-cell-in-excel

[image]

I have several font styling as well as various colors.
Now, I would like to copy them and paste them across several worksheets in my workbook.

By far I "discovered" a good option for it, which is **Paste as link picture**.

The option seems to work well, but I still have to copy & paste it sheet by sheet.

I found some VBA code here:

https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/vba-paste-a-linked-picture-and-set-the-formula-to-a-named-range.836840/

and recorded a macro for a single copy & paste, which looks like this:

```
 Range("L8:O8").Select
 Selection.Copy
 Sheets("Mux Location").Select
 Range("L8:O8").Select
 ActiveSheet.Pictures.Paste(Link:=True).Select
 ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Picture 6")).Select
 Range("A1:J17").Select
```

but what worries me is a lack of the standard PasteSpecial Xl Pastevalues. I have some image array instead.

How can I do the batch copy of the multiple formatted text to other worksheets at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit the same cell across multiple sheets in the same workbook without VBA.
You just select all the sheets you want to edit together, this also works for pasting ranges.

E.g. to copy and paste that range you would:

1. copy the cell / range to clipboard as normal (`L8:O8` in your example)
2. select all the sheets to paste into by holding CTRL + clicking them, e.g. `Sheet2` and `Sheet3` are selected here:
   [image: multiple sheets selected]
3. select the cell / range to paste into and paste as required (normal, text-only etc)
4. make sure you select another sheet to "ungroup" them, or you could overwrite cells by mistake

**Note** - this only works if the pasted cells are in the same place on each sheet, so if all sheets need pasting to range `L8:O8` then you're fine.